# using serialPort library with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I use Node Version 14.17.6 and I would like to read one of the serial ports of the computer through Angular.
I'm not sure if it can be done directly from Angular and I would like to know if maybe it's only possible through NodeJs.
I installed serialPort like this:

```
npm install serialport@11.0.0
```

So once the package is installed can I use it independent of both Angular and NodeJS?
inside appComponent.ts I imported like this:

```
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport';
```

and added it to the Imports array:

```
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SerialPort
  ]
```

at this point, without trying to use it inside the code but when i start the server i get this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/serialport/dist/serialport.d.ts:4:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (serialport) which declares SerialPort has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

4 export declare class SerialPort<T extends AutoDetectTypes = AutoDetectTypes> extends SerialPortStream<T> {
```

I also tried uninstalling and installing version 10 and when I start the server I get:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:8:10 - error TS2459: Module '"../../../../../../../Users/Work Day/Desktop/Ang/projectX/node_modules/@types/serialport"' declares 'SerialPort' locally, but it is not exported.

8 import { SerialPort } from 'serialport';
           ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/serialport/index.d.ts:13:15
    13 declare class SerialPort extends Stream.Duplex {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~
    'SerialPort' is declared here.
  node_modules/@types/serialport/index.d.ts:48:19
    48 declare namespace SerialPort {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: That library will only work on node as you guessed. However, there is a serial port API in the browser (only supported by Chrome/Edge so far though) that you can have a look at. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SerialPort

Comment: in easy words, the modue you imported is not an angular module that's why error is coming use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-serial

Comment: I was wondering one thing. I have on the same pc Angular and Node. Can the communication only be through a REST call or are there simpler ways?